# CDI validation on received parameter

Tags: java, rest, cdi, validation, facade

I am trying to understand CDI, with very few results at the moment. :(
Actually I am stucked with a web service facade like this example:

```
@GET
@Path("/greeting/{name}")
@produces(mediatype.text_plain)
public String sayHello(@PathParam("name") String name)
{
    return "Hello " + name;
}
```

Because using CDI annotation I'd like to make a check on server side every time a string is sent as parameter, to have comething like : (note `@NameValidator` annotation)

```
@GET
@Path("/greeting/{name}")
@Produces(mediatype.text_plain)
public String sayHello( @NameValidator @PathParam("name") String name)
{
    return "Hello " + name;
}
```

The validaton can be anything like that, in an external class:

```
if (name == "Andrea") {
    throw new Exception();}
```

How does it work? Is it possible? If not, what are alternatives?
Thank you!
Andrea

Answer (score 3):

You could use [CDI's interceptor annotations](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/interceptors.html) and do something like:

```
...
@Validated
public String sayHello(@Validator(MyValidator.class) String name) {
    ...
```

Where `@Validated` binds the method to a `ValidationInterceptor` class or so, where you use an `@AroundInvoke` method and its `InvocationContext` parameter to inspect the passed parameters and validate them.

One "difficulty" with this approach is that you will have to use reflection to get the `@Validator` annotation and specified validator class for each parameter, then create/retrieve corresponding instances before you can finally do the actual validation.

A slightly different approach would be to inject an `Instance<T>` of a common superclass/interface of your validators into the `ValidationInterceptor` and annotate the `sayHello` parameters with validator qualifiers:

```
// in ValidationInterceptor:

@Inject
private Instance<Validator> validatorInstance;

@AroundInvoke
public Object validate(InvocationContext context) {

    // get Annotation instances for target method parameters
    // ...

    Validator validator =
        validatorInstance.select(annotations).get();

    // ... validator.validate(parameter); ...

}

// sayHello:

...
@Validated
public String sayHello(@NameValidator String name) {
    ...
```

To get parameter annotations from `InvocationContext`, do something like:

```
Annotation[][] annotations = context.getMethod().getParameterAnnotations();
```

You may also consider pre-processing these annotations in an `@AfterBeanDiscovery` event handler.

Answer (score 3):

For that validation issue I would propose [Seam Validation](http://seamframework.org/Seam3/ValidationModule), which bridges CDI to [Hibernate-Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html). That hooks you on the well-defined validation-API of Hibernate end enables you to write code like this:

```
public void registerUser(@Valid UserData data) {...};
```

If you can't live with the Seam 3 dependency you can easily take the relevant source code of the CDI-extension, it's just a few dozens lines of code.